# Is there any active Lex and Yacc IRC?

Tags: yacc, bison, lex

Please I am searching for an active Lex and Yacc or Bison IRC - (Internet Relay Chat). Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why don't you just ask your questions here? The nonimmediate nature means that you'll get _many_ more answers than on an IRC channel, and the first one will probably be as fast as IRC, simply because there are people here just waiting for questions :-)

Comment: And if you need to talk to an expert in realtime, stackoverflow has chat too :)

Answer (score 7):

```
irc.freenode.com ##parsers
```

Not Yacc specific, but there certainly are some gurus.